# How to prove Set-Cover problem is NP hard via reduction from Clique problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, polynomial-time-reductions, set-cover, clique

Since I know that the reduction **Clique** $\leq_{p}$ **Vertex-Cover** and **Vertex-Cover** $\leq_{p}$ **Set-Cover**  are possible, I know how to show this using transitivity property of reductions. However is there a direct reduction from **Clique** to **Set-Cover** problem possible ? I have not found any reductions on this in the internet. How can we achieve **Clique** $\leq_{p}$ **Set-Cover** without using transitivity ?

Comment: Vertex Cover is just a restriction of Set Cover, so any reduction from Vertex Cover to Clique is also a reduction from Set Cover to Clique.